# Monero GUI quits within a few seconds after launching

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I am trying to get Monero GUI working, but it quits within a few seconds of launching, without displaying a dialog.
The Windows error message is:

monero-wallet-gui.exe has stopped working

Here is my data:

--- Windows 7 Pro
--- Monero downloaded as;  monero-gui-win-x64-v0.11.0.0.zip
--- I tried putting the path to the Monero directory in the Windows system PATH environment variable
--- I tried launching the GUI with a CMD file that specifies the complete path to the executable
--- there are no blank spaces in the path to the executable
--- the daemon, monerod.exe seems to run without a hitch
--- the CLI executable seems to run without a hitch and I was able to create a new wallet
--- in the file,  monero-wallet-gui.log,  I have the following error messages:

2017-10-03 15:45:10.500 2828    INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:148   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO

2017-10-03 15:45:23.217 2828    INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:156   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO

I would REALLY like to get the GUI up and running.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
rp108

Comment: There should be a script called run-low-graphics or similar. Try that one.

Comment: It is working now !

Comment: Great, I've made this into a short answer then. And btw, those "error messages" aren't error messages. They're telling you what logs are active.

Comment: OK. I see.  Good insight. Looking forward to start mining Monero. It's been hard to make much coin with BitCoin and LiteCoin these days.

Answer (score 3):

monero-wallet-gui uses Qt, which uses OpenGL by default, and this does not play well with some machines. For this reason, monero-wallet-gui includes a script called `start-low-graphics-mode.bat` to run in fallback mode, which should be compatible with more machines, but at the cost of (I believe) some graphical glitches.

Comment: Thank-you. Appreciate your insight. I have it working now.

Answer (score 0):

Installing directx 9.0c runtime could solve this without low graphics mode.
 https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8109&751be11f-ede8-5a0c-058c-2ee190a24fa6=True

Comment: Thnak-you for this info. I am following the link now. All the best.